# How to apply MVC pattern on combobox with javafx and database source (in this case SQLite)

Tags: sqlite, combobox, javafx-8

i am trying to transform my previous javafx program into an MVC machine. i actually do not have any compilation error neither do i have runtime errors. but when i run my login application i cannot see the database values in the combobox.

yes of course i can login, it works fine.

This are my codes for the combobox splited into LoginView, LoginController, and LoginModel:

```
package com.login;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * Created by DELL PC on 7/25/2016.
 */
public class LoginModel {
    Connection connection;

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    public LoginModel()
    {
        connection = SqliteConnection.connector();

        if(connection == null)
       {
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

    public boolean isDBConnected()
   {
    try {
        return !connection.isClosed();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

public ComboBox fillCombobox()
{
    try
    {
        final ObservableList options = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        String query = "SELECT role from admin";
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        while(resultSet.next())
        {
            options.add(resultSet.getString("role"));
        }
        preparedStatement.close();
        resultSet.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}

public boolean isLogin(String user, String pass) throws SQLException
{
    String query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = ? and password = ?";

    try {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, user);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, pass);

        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        if(resultSet.next())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        preparedStatement.close();
        resultSet.close();
    }
}
```

}

code for Controller

```
 package com.login;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class LoginController implements Initializable{

    public LoginModel loginModel = new LoginModel();

    @FXML
    private TextField txtusername;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField pwpaswword;

    @FXML
    private Label isConnected;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox comboBox;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        comboBox.getItems().contains(loginModel.fillCombobox());

    if(loginModel.isDBConnected())
    {
        isConnected.setText("Connected");
    }
    else
    {
        isConnected.setText("Not Connected");
    }
}

public void Login(ActionEvent event)
{
    try {
            if (loginModel.isLogin(txtusername.getText(), pwpaswword.getText()))
            {
                isConnected.setText("Login Successfully ");

                ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();

                Stage window = new Stage();
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                Pane root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("CivilStateView.fxml").openStream());

                CivilStateController civilStateController = (CivilStateController)loader.getController();
                civilStateController.getUser(txtusername.getText());

                Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                window.setTitle("Hello World");
                window.setScene(scene);
                window.show();
            }
            else
            {
                isConnected.setText("Login Unsuccessful");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            isConnected.setText("Exception occurred:" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

the view is made with fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="346.0" prefWidth="360.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.login.LoginController">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="isConnected" layoutX="31.0" layoutY="30.0" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Status" textFill="#f20f0f">
     <font>
        <Font size="18.0" />
     </font>
  </Label>
  <TextField fx:id="txtusername" layoutX="26.0" layoutY="75.0" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="160.0" promptText="Username">
     <font>
        <Font size="19.0" />
     </font>
  </TextField>
  <PasswordField fx:id="pwpaswword" layoutX="26.0" layoutY="137.0" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="160.0" promptText="Password">
     <font>
        <Font size="19.0" />
     </font>
  </PasswordField>
  <ComboBox fx:id="comboBox" layoutX="26.0" layoutY="196.0" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="150.0">
          <padding>
             <Insets left="20.0" />
          </padding>
      </ComboBox>
      <Button layoutX="26.0" layoutY="245.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Login" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="68.0" text="Button" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Please help over here. Thanks

Comment: You're never actually putting anything into the ComboBox. Change the fillCombobox() method so it returns the ObservableList you create and populate, then change the line in your initialise method to `comboBox.setItems(loginModel.fillCombobox());`

Comment: Thanks very much Geoff. i did exactly that but when i declare the combobox in the controller and i use the line you suggested, it does not show any error but the variable combobox in the declaration seems not to be used. it seems to mean that the line actually does not use the actual combobox variable declared above, thus still not filling the values

Comment: 'private combobox is never assigned'   that is what they say.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create a test case that runs this though not using any of the DB interaction. The critical parts are:

```
public class LoginModel {
    ...
    public ObservableList fillCombobox() {
        ObservableList options = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        // replace this with your DB code to add the options.
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            options.add("Role " + i);
        }
        //
        return options;
    }
}

public class LoginController implements Initializable {
    ...
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        comboBox.setItems(loginModel.fillCombobox());
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: i have another issue

Comment: You should create a new question if you have a different issue, I think that's the preferred way of doing things here. It's also a good idea to accept answers if they fix the problem so others aren't inclined to keep trying to find an answer for you.

Comment: Certainly your attempt to answer my question was a great success Goeff. My apology not to have mentioned it before. I really was able to make it thanks.